# Where can I find Java API code

Tags: java

I heard that Java is a opensource code. so, Can I get Java API coding methodology? If so, please let me know where can I get the source code for Java APIs.

Answer (score 6):

You can find it in the `src.zip` in the JDK installation directory.

From [`Java docs`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/README.html#contents):

> Source Code:
>         (In src.zip) JavaTM programming language source files for all classes that make up the Java core API (that is, sources files for the java.*, javax.* and some org.* packages, but not for com.sun.* packages). This source code is provided for informational purposes only, to help developers learn and use the JavaTM programming language. These files do not include platform-specific implementation code and cannot be used to rebuild the class libraries. To extract these file, use any common zip utility. Or, you may use the Jar utility in the JDK's bin/ directory:

```
jar xvf src.zip
```

Comment: Your IDE may also provide a `Go to reference` command that let you access the source code in src.zip when you use it on a method of the Java class library.